# jQuery ctrl + scroll zoom

Tags: jquery, scroll, zooming

Is there a way to execute the control + scroll function on click ? I want people to be able to zoom in on a website by clicking on a button and I think this is the easiest way because all browsers have this function. I only need the way to call this function from within jQuery.

Comment: I don't think the browsers zoom-function is exposed to javascript. That would be a very Bad Thing...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647237/can-i-zoom-into-a-web-page-like-ie-or-firefox-do-using-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.

But if you build your website with `em` or `%` and not `px` you will have a easier job when you need to enlarge the website.

There might be better options, but it really depends on why you want to do this.

You can read when to use what here: [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)