# Different zoom levels shows different information

Tags: html, zooming

I was wondering if it's possible to have different levels of zoom which can shows differents levels of information.
It's probably not really clear so the idea is that :

At normal zoom : only images
Maximum zoom : caption of the images
Minimum zoom :  symbols corresponding to images (like pictogram)

And it could be really great if these layers can mix themselves with an idea of transparency.
Zoom between minimum and normal would show images at 50% of opacity and their symbols at the same level of opacity.

Thanks you in advance,
JJulien

Comment: Do you want to implement a zoom feature in your website, or just adjust to the browser's zoom setting?

Comment: With a zoom feature, i think it'll be easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a zoom feature to only some parts of your website: This can be done in JavaScript; You can set a different `class` on your body-element for each zoom level, and then define which contents are displayed in a style sheet.

[Look at this JSFiddle for a rough concept.](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzMd/)

If you want to implement a zoom for all of your website, not just parts, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464038/imitate-browser-zoom-with-javascript).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's exactly what I wanted, I'll try to improve the code to use opacity and if I got problems I'll be back :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Accepting the answer would be appreciated if it was helpful to you.