# How to detect zoom event and set zoom in Chrome on current page programmatically?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, zooming

Chrome can be [zoomed in or out](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> (Windows).

And I also noticed that some webpages can detective if current page is zoomed or not.

How do they get that good and is there any Webkit or HTML5 API can zoom Chrome on current page programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In css:

```
zoom: 150%
```

Appply this css property to body

Or in js

```
$(document.body).css('zoom','150%')
```

To catch zoom event there are several techics ( check zoom on 'resize' for example ) - check this topic [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

1.detect page zoom event:

- [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713771/1299675)
- [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995914/1299675)

2.page zoom:

- http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/
- http://www.perlunity.de/javascript/scripts/javascript_0314_main.shtml
- [imitate browser zoom with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10464038/1299675)