# Javascript Browser zoom object

Tags: javascript, webi

I am trying write a Javascript function which runs on a button click event in **SAP WEBI**, which makes the **browser zoom to 80%**.

I am trying to use this code which works in case of a standard website (it does not use browser zoom but actually zooms in on the *element* which the button is in, however in the case of a webi it actually does nothing)

**Script:**

```
function fullscreen() {
    document.body.style.zoom = "80%";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="1" onClick="fullscreen()">full screen view</button>
```

Any help on how I could make the browser zoom back to 80% scale in SAP WEBI?

Answer (score 1):

Use the decimal value not the percentage

```
 document.body.style.zoom = 0.8
```

see [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093570/force-page-zoom-at-100-with-js)

Comment: Thank you seems to work although I've noticed the problem should happen with IE. looks like in ie case the API does not take in consideration javascript codes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any way to Zoom-in or Zoom-out your browser this way, some browsers provide their APIs for the purpose but I'm not sure.

One way I can suggest is to zoom-out your entire DOM by using Javascript

```
document.body.style.zoom=1.0;
this.blur();
```

1.0 means 100%

0.8 means 80% **(Your case)**

150% would be 1.5

1000% would be 10.0

and so on.

`this.blur()` means that the curser, maybe you selected an input field, looses focus of every select item.([Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10464073/3677277))

Comment: Thank you seems to work although I've noticed the problem should happen with IE. looks like in ie case the API does not take in consideration javascript codes

But nevertheless I will use your solution in chrome case.

Comment: Have you tried it with IE? Zoom is actually a CSS3 property and works fine with IE.

Comment: Yeah yeah. Sadly it worked on chrome case but in IE case totally disregarded it. Maybe because of the WEBI API

Comment: Well I haven't tested it with WEBI, maybe that is the issue. I'll give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: Thank you :) It can happen that I've done something wrong. I am quite new to SAP webintelligence therefore mistakes can be made but as I said worked in chrome so I am quessing it has something to do with IE.

Answer (score 0):

first you should know that zoom is a non-standard property, use transform instead

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

[zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

you could use `transform`

```js
document.body.style.webkitTransform =         
  document.body.style.msTransform =          
  document.body.style.transform = 'scale(5)';
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur similique cumque fugiat omnis quisquam ex harum. Quisquam ea velit architecto qui illum esse nesciunt earum nisi in voluptas ratione voluptatum!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work although I've noticed the problem should happen with IE. looks like in ie case the API does not take in consideration javascript codes