# Can you emulate the zoom feature in chrome desktop

Tags: javascript, css

Has anyone been able to emulate chromes zoom using css or javascript ?

I've tried using REM , css zoom and scale and can not reproduce how Chrome zoom is working.

When i use chrome zoom it perfectly increases the page size and adjust all media query breakpoints perfectly. Using REM for all font sizes , widths ect , when i change base font size the breakpoints in "rem" or "em" don't scale like using zoom in chrome

Comment: Because zoom changes width and height of the document

Comment: might be a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69560524/6827830

Comment: thanks, nothing there works remotely properly to emulate chromes zoom

Comment: Try to increase font ans the image sizes.