# Zoom In My Website By 10%

Tags: css, zooming

After finishing a website design for a client, I realized that everything was kind of small.  After experimenting with the browser zoom, I found that zooming in 10% fixed a lot!  The problem is, I can't figure out how to resize EVERYTHING (div sizes, image sizes, text sizes, etc.) to 110%.

Any ideas are appreciated.  I would prefer to do this all in CSS.

## Edit -

Haha, OK guys, I guess I'll just go in and actually spend some time changing the sizes.  It isn't what I wanted to do but I guess it is my only real option.  Thanks guys :)

Comment: What's wrong with changing all your size values to be 10% larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to redesign your website. If you have designed correctly, this should be *very* easy. Some advice:

- Page width: Increase the width of your outermost container, child element widths *should* expand to fill the space unless you have hardcoded absolute widths set. In those cases, adjust the `px` to accommodate.
- Font size: If you have used `em` or `%` values, just increase the `font-size` of `body` (the other elements will inherit this base font size). If you have used `px` for font sizes, you'll have to increase them.

I think you know deep down that "zooming" the page via javascript or the IE `zoom` property isn't the right approach and you are avoiding the redesign. Even something like `body{ transform:scale(1.1); }` is going to make your images look bad when they scale/stretch, and since it's CSS3 the support will be lacking, and [after testing this idea](http://jsfiddle.net/qddpX/) it appears to be able to scale content out of the viewport/visible area.

The right way to do it if you want this to be permanent change is to rewrite your CSS.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll stop being lazy and actually go fix it :3  +1 for calling me out on my inside feelings.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to solve the issue in an other way (setting font size 10px up etc.)

But if you really want to do that I referr you to my recent answer on a similar issue. Be careful because FF does not support this, because FF does not allow zooming via js!

[imitate browser zoom with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464038/imitate-browser-zoom-with-javascript/10464073#10464073)

> [There you go:][1]
>
> Use:
>
> ```
> document.body.style.zoom=1.0;this.blur();
> ```
>
> 1.0 means 100%
>
> 150% would be 1.5 1000% would be 10.0
>
> this.blur() means that the curser, maybe you selected an input field,
>   looses focus of every select item.
>
> or:
>
> You can use the css3 element [zoom][2] ([Source][3])
>
> [Firefox does not allow][4] zooming with the browser because you can't
>   access the user properties via javascript or sth.
>
> So you can just use some CSS styles which allow to zoom (CSS3: zoom,
>   as mentioned above) or to increase the text size! Which you could do
>   with including a different CSS file for example. But here you have the
>   "jumpy" problem, because the styled css elements (floated etc.) have
>   to "interact" different in fact of their attributes.
>
> The zoom I posted above works well in Chrome and IE8+ (FF not
>   supported as mentioned)
>
> [1]:
>   http://www.perlunity.de/javascript/scripts/javascript_0314_main.shtml 
>   [2]: http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/   [3]:
>   [Can I zoom into a web page like IE or Firefox do, using programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647237/can-i-zoom-into-a-web-page-like-ie-or-firefox-do-using-programming)
>   [4]:
>   http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html

Comment: Really really bad idea to try to fix a design by trying to change the zoom setting.

Answer (score 1):

This resizes everything on the screen to 200% scale in all the worth-while browsers:

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```