# Scalable sites with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scalability, parallax

Trying to create a site with jQuery parallax that resizes correctly when shrinking or enlarging the window. Look at the at this flash site and drag the corners to see the resizing functionality.

http://www.intersectionpartners.com/

Any advice on how to do this with jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "scalable"? A zoom effect on the entire website? If so, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647237/can-i-zoom-into-a-web-page-like-ie-or-firefox-do-using-programming

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you expect is parallax in fullscreen. Like in my sample here:

http://jsfiddle.net/protron/hLHTP/embedded/result/ (full source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/protron/hLHTP/))

I started my copying they [target demo](http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/target.html) and then (inside the CSS) I set the margins to "0" for `parallax-port`:

```
.parallax-port {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
}
```

That's about it. Then I changed the images to the one in their [parallax homepage](http://stephband.info/jparallax/), and changed their cordinates to get a sampler similar to the page you showed (but obviously the images are not big enough for a big screen).